# Apply function on numpy array row-by-row incrementaly

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, optimization

How can I optimize the following code, or more specifically, how can I eliminate the for-loop?

```
array = np.zeros((x.shape[0], K), dtype=np.float128)
for k in range(K):
    array[:, k] = np.prod((np.power(ms[k, :], x) * np.power(1 - ms[k, :], 1 - x)).astype('float128'), axis=1)
```

where x is a two-dimensional array shaped like [70000, 784] and ms like [K, 784] and K=10.

Edit: after it was brought up to my attention, the desired code is fixed.

Comment: Please provide small example arrays (e.g. `x` with shape `(7, 8)` and `ms` with shape `(K, 8)` and expected output. A minimal reproducible example is strongly recommended (if not rquired) on Stack Overflow questions, and helps the community answer your question faster.

Comment: Also, your `for` loop does not work. It's impossible for us to know what you want when the example code doesn't work.

Comment: `ms[k,:]` is (784,) shape.  `np.power(ms[k,:],x])` is (70000,784) shape.  That won't fit in the (70000,) shape `array[:,k]`.

Answer (score 0):

With 2 arrays with smaller dimensions:

```
In [142]: K=5; x=np.arange(30*4).reshape(30,4); ms = np.arange(K*4).reshape(K,4)
```

Your iterative solution looks like:

```
In [143]: np.array([np.power(ms[k,:],x) for k in range(K)]).shape
Out[143]: (5, 30, 4)

In [144]: arr = np.array([np.power(ms[k,:],x) for k in range(K)])

In [145]: arr.shape
Out[145]: (5, 30, 4)
```

A equivalent solution without the loop:

```
In [146]: arr1 = np.power(ms[:,None,:],x)
In [147]: arr1.shape
Out[147]: (5, 30, 4)

In [148]: np.allclose(arr,arr1)
Out[148]: True
```

Comment: I've added something. 
Alttough your proposed solution results in a 3-d array. My desired output is like array = [x.shape[0], K].